# Login Azure Automation account, without user credential, to Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

is possible to connect with an azure automation account to azuread with cmdlet:

- MsOnline Module
- AzureAD Module

without use credential stored in automation account?

[image]

I'm using following code with credential and works fine:

```
$azureadcred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'AzureAD'
Connect-AzureAD -credential $azureadcred

$o365cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'O365'
Connect-Msolservice -credential $o365cred
```

Any  help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: is that ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

> How to connect AzureAD module without user

We can use the service principal to connect module AzureAD. Meanwhile,  you use the Azure Automation Account, we can directly use [Azure Automation Run As accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account) to connect the module.

The detailed steps are as below.

1. Assign [Azure AD role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) to the Run As accounts.
   a. Get the object id of the Run As accounts
      [image]

   b. assign role

```
 Connect-AzureAD 

 $role =Get-AzureADDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Company Administrator'" 

    Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId <the object id you copy>
```

2. PowerShell Script

```
 $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'
 $connectState = Connect-AzAccount `
       -ServicePrincipal `
       -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
       -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
       -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
 if ($connectState) {
        "Connected."
    } else {
        "Doesn't seem to be connected."
    }
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$context.Account
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken

$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $context.tenant.id -AccountId $context.Account.Id -AzureEnvironmentName $context.Environment.Name -AadAccessToken $aadToken -MsAccessToken $graphToken 

get-azureaduser -Top 5
```

Comment: Hi Jim, i have ti test it. I Will let you know today or Tomorrow :). It Is good also for connect-msolservice?

Comment: @Emanuele, Hi Emanuele, how are you doing, hope you have a good day. Did you succeed on connect-msolservice without a admin user credential? I also got this problem, when I connect-msolservice I got InvalidHeader error.

Comment: Hi @Devssssss i'm good thanks, hope you too. I remember that i had to use admin credential and after that with didn't continue to test that flow  :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ! @Emanuele, have a nice day!